# HDFS stress test in multi-node Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, benchmarking

I have set up a multi-node Hadoop cluster. I'm intended to test the performance of the HDFS without using MR. Is there such a benchmark in Hadoop test jar?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**TestDFSIO:**

1. The default output directory is /benchmarks/TestDFSIO
2. Run write tests before read tests

The syntax for running a **write test** is as follows:

```
TestDFSIO.0.0.4
Usage: hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/hadoop-*test*.jar TestDFSIO -read | -write | -clean [-nrFiles N] [-fileSize MB] [-resFile resultFileName] [-bufferSize Bytes]
```

Eg: The command to run a write test that generates 10 output files of size 1GB for a total of 10GB is:

`$ hadoop jar hadoop-*test*.jar TestDFSIO -write -nrFiles 10 -fileSize 1000`

Similarly, read test using 10 input files of size 1GB is:

```
$ hadoop jar hadoop-*test*.jar TestDFSIO -read -nrFiles 10 -fileSize 1000
```

Clean up and remove test data using: `$ hadoop jar hadoop-*test*.jar TestDFSIO -clean`

**Interpreting TestDFSIO results:**

Sample:

```
----- TestDFSIO ----- : write
           Date & time: Fri Apr 08 2011
       Number of files: 1000
Total MBytes processed: 1000000
     Throughput mb/sec: 4.989
Average IO rate mb/sec: 5.185
 IO rate std deviation: 0.960
    Test exec time sec: 1113.53

----- TestDFSIO ----- : read
           Date & time: Fri Apr 08 2011
       Number of files: 1000
Total MBytes processed: 1000000
     Throughput mb/sec: 11.349
Average IO rate mb/sec: 22.341
 IO rate std deviation: 119.231
    Test exec time sec: 544.842
```

The most notable metrics here are ***Throughput mb/sec*** and ***Average IO rate mb/sec***.

[image: Throughput]

[image: Average IO rate]

[Source](http://www.michael-noll.com/blog/2011/04/09/benchmarking-and-stress-testing-an-hadoop-cluster-with-terasort-testdfsio-nnbench-mrbench/)